# Check link click happen within a div

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the Javascript returning true when users click on the links within specific div

For example:
When users click on links in div having class="span1", it will return true

```
<div class="span1">
   <h3>Title 3</h3>
      <ul class="stages" dir="ltr">
          <li><a href="http://www.example.com" >Example 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.example.com" >Example 2</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div class="span2">
   <h3>Title 4</h3>
      <ul class="stages" dir="ltr">
          <li><a href="http://www.example.com" >Example 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.example.com" >Example 2</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What have you tried to make this happen? What problems have you encountered using this approach?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do and what the goal is better?  Also, any javascript code you have to this point would help, even if it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an `if` statement for `.hasClass`:

```
$("div").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("span1")){
    alert("SPAN 1 CLICKED");
    return true;
  }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xxx96bta/3/)

**UPDATE**: I read your question too quick, here is a new fiddle which targets your `a`'s instead of the `div`

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xxx96bta/4/)

should be this instead:

```
if($(this).closest("div").hasClass("span1")){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I cannot see any alert when I clicked on the links, may I ask why is that so?

Comment: bcz it returned `true` before alert!
Actually no return is needed i think... @jmore009.

Comment: just the order of the alert and `return true`. I changed it.

Comment: Appreciate your help, allow me to learn more from you guys.

Can I use plain javascript instead of jquery to perform the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Here in pure Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/xxx96bta/5/

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); //collect your elements

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    (function () {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', whatSpan, false);
    })();
}

function whatSpan() {
    var parentspan = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className;
    if (parentspan == "span1") {
        alert("you clicked span 1");
    } else {
        alert("you clicked span 2");
    }

}
```